# I would like to move a div when an alert is displayed

Tags: css, angular

I would like to move a div when my alert is activated my div go down to let the alert be displayed correctly and when alert this disactively the div comes back to its original place

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Share some codes

Comment: you can try like this https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `[ngClass]` (https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and by condition change your class e.g. 
HTML

```
<div [ngClass]="getClass()">
```

TS

```
getClass():string{
return (your.condition === true)? 'cssClass1': 'cssClass2' ;
}
```

Where 'cssClass1' and 'cssClass2' is the names of css classes you have already defined in your styles.css